# CURL issue in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to put PVOutputs API CURL commands into my development but they cant seem to do it.

The CURL command is: `curl -H "X-Pvoutput-Apikey: Your-API-Key" -H "X-Pvoutput-SystemId: Your-System-Id" https://pvoutput.org/service/r2/getoutput.jsp`

and heres how i tried it using http requests:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SolarGridx',
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.white),
      home: CurlScreen(),
    );
  }
}

var responseJson;

class CurlScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text(responseJson)));
  }
}

Future<void> EnergyInfo() async {
  String url = 'https://pvoutput.org/service/r2/getoutput.jsp';
  Map<String, String> headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Pvoutput-Apikey": "064154d4ee89b29f195179ff5fbd30c908fddf45",
    "X-Pvoutput-SystemId": "77117",
  };
  var response = await http.post(url, headers: headers);

  int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  print('This is the statuscode: $statusCode');
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseJson);

  print('This is the API response: $responseJson');
}
```

I have also tried using CURL dependencies but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an issue with your flutter code . if possible enrich your question with the output/errors displayed in the console.

It seems to me that the curl request `curl -H "X-Pvoutput-Apikey: Your-API-Key" -H "X-Pvoutput-SystemId: Your-System-Id"` has a `GET` http method whereas in your flutter code you do a `POST`.

So in order to fix that you would have to change `await http.post(url, headers: headers);` to `await http.get(url, headers: headers);`.

Also please note that you shouldn't post your api key here since stackoverflow is a public site.

Using your api key I was able to retrieve a response from the api and it seems that it does not return json responses. It returns a comma separated plain text response.

So this code will probably raise an exception.

```
final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
```

You could try to just print the `response.body` to see in what format the response is.

If it is a comma separated string then you could do the following to `split` the response and get the relevant parts

```
List<String> results = response.body.split(',')
```